# Basic Flask OpenID Connect example

Tags: flask, openid-connect

With the impending shutdown of Google's support for OpenID 2, anyone using a convenient library like [Flask-Googleauth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-GoogleAuth/0.3) will have to migrate. There is a Flask library for OpenID Connect, called [flask-oidc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask-oidc). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any info out there on how to use it. I looked for SO questions tagged `flask` and `openid-connect`, but found zero, hence this question.

Here's what I've put together as a proof-of-concept use of flask-oidc. It's based on [flask-oidc's app.py file](https://github.com/SteelPangolin/flask-oidc/blob/master/tests/app.py):

```
"""
Flask app for testing the OpenID Connect extension.
"""
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.oidc import OpenIDConnect

def index():
    return "too many secrets", 200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
    }

def create_app(config, oidc_overrides=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(config)
    if oidc_overrides is None:
        oidc_overrides = {}
    oidc = OpenIDConnect(app, **oidc_overrides)
    app.route('/')(oidc.check(index))
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = create_app({
        'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': './client_secrets.json',
        'SECRET_KEY': 'secret'})
    APP.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

After registering my application as described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect), this successfully sends the user to Google for authentication, and returns them to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/oidc_callback`, which then redirects them to `https://127.0.0.1:8080/`, but that then redirects the user back to Google for authentication, creating a redirect loop.

My question, of course, is simple: how can I get an authenticated user to see that index page?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that oidc_callback is correctly creating an authentication cookie (called `oidc_id_token`) and redirecting to `index`, but `index` can't retrieve that cookie because the app is hosted on HTTP, and the cookie has the [Secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) set, so the browser is unwilling to send it back to the app over HTTP.

The solution is (for local development purposes only!) to turn off the Secure flag, by setting the OpenIDConnect config item `OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE` to `False`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = create_app({
        'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': './client_secrets.json',
        'OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE': False,
        'SECRET_KEY': 'secret'})
    APP.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have success running the Nosetest suite in flask-oidc, but I repeatedly got a redirect_uri mismatch error back from Google, with the message "http://localhost:8080/oidc_callback did not match a registered redirect URI." The test suite client.secrets lists the redirect URI as http://localhost:5000/oauth2callback. Neither worked for me, because I was changing them and running the code a few minutes later. When I changed the credentials and re-tried hours later, it worked.